# Forward objects when using Intent

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm using `Intent(context, destinationClass)` to switch activities. However, I would like to bring some objects along to the next acitivty. I know about `putExtra`, but I only find methods usable for strings, integers, etc.

I'm forwarding a socket if that's any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of options to accomplish what you're looking for.

- Create static objects that are publicly accessible
- Create your own extension of `Application` have it implement getters/setters for your variables.
- Have the objects you want to add as `Intent` extra implement [`Parcelable`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html).
- ...
- ... etc

It shouldn't be too hard to find something that fits your specific needs.

Comment: How do you get a socket to implement Parcelable?

Comment: You don't, and I'm not saying you can. I'm merely posing some suggestions to the implicit yet generic question "Forward objects when using Intent" that may of help for people having a similar problem statement.

Answer (score 2):

If you're firing up another activity in the same application, I'd suggest using a static object that both activities can access. Don't try to communicate it via an intent. (If you have several sockets, you could have several static objects and communicate via the intent which one to use.)